# Would this freeze time for the entity/object described?

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, physics, space

Pretend for a moment that you were traveling in our solar system at the exact opposite speed of the Sun rotation, and on an inverted axis such that you always stay in the exact same position relative to the sun, and within our solar system in respect to the position of the other planets.

The intention is that your place in space is static, yet still within our solar system.

Will time stop?

Assuming also that time is nothing more than the movement of particles, would the only possible method of freezing time be to reach absolute kelvin?

Is there any way to counter this movement? Say, travel in the opposite direction at the same rate such that your speed is always non-existent?

Comment: freeze who's time?

Comment: @user6760 good point! The entity and/or object in the current State described above. I’ll modify to State this.

Comment: your question is totally unclear: how can you move in the opposite direction of something, yet being static with respect to it? how can you state that time is the consequence of particle movement?

Comment: @JacobGaiski you have an interesting idea, but please do make it a bit more clear what you're saying, as I'm having trouble understanding.  Of particular note is the concept of maintaining a constant position with respect to the planets.  There are several planets which are moving at different speeds (with respect to the sun); I can't quite see a scenario where one could be stationary with respect to *all* of them.  Please help me understand.

Comment: @L.Dutch it's not unclear. The author started with a wrong premise, so just point out that they wrong. He thought that if you remain stationary in space, time will stop. I wonder how he got to that conclusion myself, though.

Comment: @Vylix, do you find "traveling in our solar system at the exact opposite speed of the Sun rotation, and on an inverted axis such that you always stay in the exact same position relative to the sun" clear?

Comment: @L.Dutch after I read it again, the first sentence doesn't make sense, neither "inverted axis", but I managed to understand what he meant with "always stay in the exact same position relative to the sun". See my analogue to treadmill. Imagine that our earth revolution around the sun is like the treadmill, and you are trying to stay in the same position (by whatever means). @ Jacob did I get that right?

Comment: Physics says (1) time has nothing to do with the motion of planets - motion is not a source for time, (2) you cannot reach $0^{\circ}$K and (c) you cannot freeze time.  Lastly it sounds like you have no understanding of basic relativity, which I'd suggest you develop if this interests you.  There is no notion of absolute position in time or space.  Even the idea of two events being simultaneous is problematic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, know that the solar system is moving relative to the galaxy center, and Milky Way to the other galaxies. Heck, even galaxies are [moving away from each other!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_expansion_of_space)

What you do will only make you stationary relative to the solar system, at most.

And what you do will not freeze time, not for you, not to the solar system, not to the galaxy. Think like this:

> You are running on a treadmill. You will remain stationary (approximately), but you will still age, won't you?

And 0 K does not freeze *anyone's* time, either. It's just that the atoms on that human stop moving, so it looks he's frozen in time. Well, to be precise, he is *indeed frozen*, **but not in time.**

It does in some sense *preserve* the body, if that's what you are looking for. Just as putting meat in a freezer prevents it from rotting (by killing or forcing the bacteria to hibernate, and *slowing* chemical reaction), putting someone in 0 K completely stops the rotting of the body (instead of slowing it), effectively freezing them "in time".

It is questionable that the person will still alive after that though ;)

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Very nice. Question. Do you propose that time can almost never be frozen considering the sheer amount of near infinite variables that must be addressed? It would still seem that since time is defined as movement through space, that if you freeze the space and an entity cannot move, therefore time has been stopped as well?

Comment: I see your edit. Nope! I’m trying to think of a way to theoretically stop all of time and essentially pause the entire universe. Seems like you may have to default to logical removal of time to then consider it being frozen and/or stopped. Meaning, before the Big Bang when time didn’t exist. Well, as we know it. 

Comment: @JacobGaiski right now this is just a pointer. Try to search "stop time is:q" in the search bar.

Comment: you mean in google or in stack exchange?

Comment: @JacobGaiski in Worldbuilding.Stackexchange. Go scroll up and you'll see a search bar in the middle.

Comment: Thanks. Thats interesting - I’m assuming that means as well that this question has never been answered, or we cannot comprehend this? 

Comment: @JacobGaiski if you wish to get more technical stuffs, go ahead to [physics.SE]. Try to search a bit (stop time). I think someone else must've asked this before.

Comment: Yeah, it’s sounding like the theory of relativity is at work here... the answer is probably a series of equations of which require input from another set of equations that conform and create what we call reality. Thanks, I’ll investigate and see if I can find an answer.

Comment: If time actually stopped for all of existence, we would have no way of knowing. 1,000,000 years could have passed since I started typing this comment, but since the whole universe was "put on pause" along with me we could not perceive it. If some entity was able to observe that pause from the outside, time has not stopped for him (he needs time to observe), and the whole premise of pausing the universe fails.

Answer (score 1):

Moving in the opposite direction to the Sun and your traveller will fall into the Sun under gravity. So no it won't stop time.

Freezing someone, something or anything to absolute zero won't stop time. Reaching absolute zero kelvin is impossible anyway.

Time is a dimensional property and while the relative rate of time passing is influenced by your state of motion. Only by travelling at exactly the speed of light will cause time to stop. The main problem will be starting time again, because it's extremely difficult to do things in zero time.